# Persistency in MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I wish to create the following topology using MSMQ:

- Service in server A writes messages to local queue
- The local queue in server A is a mediator to another queue in server B

That means that when the service in server A writes messages to queue in server A this queue immediately transfer this messages to the queue in Server B. If by any reason the connection to Server B is close the queue in server A aggregates the messages untill the connection is restored.

Is MSMQ support this topology

Answer (score 1):

Yes MSMQ supports this scenario. You can do that with a **Transactional MSMQ**.

**Basic Concepts of Transactional MSMQ:**

1) The beginning and end of the transaction must be indicated, so that it is known which actions are contained within that transaction.

2) If the transaction completes successfully, it is committed, which causes all the actions to become permanent and the transaction to end.

3) If the transaction fails, for whatever reason, it is aborted and a rollback occurs, undoing any actions that have already been executed before the abort.

---

In a ***Transactional MSMQ:***

The source computer keeps track of outgoing messages until it gets an order ACK from the destination. The order ACK means that the message was successfully inserted into the final destination queue on the final destination computer. If the message is successfully delivered to the next hop but the order ACK is not received, the source computer resends it after 30 seconds. The resend interval is then increased (up to six hours). If other delivery routes are available, Message Queuing will use them for resend.

When you send messages to remote queue, a temporary outgoing queue is created on your own machine. This is used in case the remote queue is unavailable. If you go to the computer Management console (compmgmt.msc), and expand the Services and Applications / Message Queuing / Outgoing Queues, you would see these queues. The right side of the console should show the details including the state (connected or not) and the IP address(es) for the next hop(s).

Message Queuing provides its own transaction confirmation process to inform the sending application either that the messages were retrieved from the queue or why the receiving application failed to retrieve them. Note that this confirmation process is completely independent of committing the transaction.

When a message is placed in the destination queue, the destination queue manager acknowledges its arrival by sending an order acknowledgement message containing its sequence number back to the source computer. This number indicates to the source queue manager that all messages in the message stream up to the acknowledged message were accepted.

Here are some links you can look up to:

1) [Transactional and Nontransactional Messaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704006(v=vs.85).aspx)

2) [Message Queuing Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699870(v=vs.85).aspx)

3) [Transaction Confirmation Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711443(v=vs.85).aspx)

4) [Reliable Messaging with MSMQ and .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx)

5) [FAQs on MSMQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/9/FC9989A2-DA75-4D96-B654-4BD29CF6AEE1/MSMQ_faq_updated.doc)